# Remove rows from data.table in R based on values of several columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R which has several ids and a value. For each combination of ids, there are several rows. If one of these rows contains NA in the column 'value', I would like to remove all rows with this combination of ids. For example, in the table below, I would like to remove all rows for which `id1 == 2` and `id2 == 1`.

If I had only one id I would do `dat[!(id1 %in% dat[is.na(value),id1])]`. In the example, this would remove all rows where i1 == 2. However, I did not manage to include several columns.

```
dat <- data.table(id1 = c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
                  id2 = c(1,2,1,2,3,1),
                  value = c(5,3,NA,6,7,3))
```

Comment: Try `dat[!(id1==2 & id2==1)]` or `setkey(dat, id1, id2)[!J(2,1) ]`

Comment: I know that this would work in the simple example above. However, the question is meant to be more general as there might be a large number of rows with NAs.

Comment: I think he is looking for `dat[, if(all(!is.na(value))) .SD, .(id1, id2)]`

Comment: @lilaf Okay, just now read the part about the `NA`.  My comment was based on `I would like to remove all rows for which id1 == 2 and id2 == 1.`

Comment: @akrun Anyway thank you for your answer, I'll try to be clearer next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check per combination of `id1` and `id2` if any of the values are `NA`s and then remove that whole combination, you can insert an `if` statement per group and only retrieve the results (using `.SD`) if that statement returns `TRUE`.

```
dat[, if(!anyNA(value)) .SD, by = .(id1, id2)]
#    id1 id2 value
# 1:   1   1     5
# 2:   1   2     3
# 3:   2   2     6
# 4:   2   3     7
```

Or similarly,

```
dat[, if(all(!is.na(value))) .SD, by = .(id1, id2)]
```

Comment: It might be costly to split `dat` into all those `.SD` and stack them. An alternative (maybe generally faster?) approach would be to select rows to keep `dat[dat[,!any(is.na(value)),by="id1,id2"]$V1]`

Comment: Ah, you're right. I did test it, but somehow convinced myself that what I saw was the right answer. The alternative I should have mentioned is: `dat[dat[,.I[!any(is.na(value))],by="id1,id2"]$V1]`

Comment: @Frank that's a nice option too.